# _Input and _Process runs twice

Tags: godot

Please note that my Godot version is 3.3 so that could be a reason.

I tried to create a script to shoot bullets.

First I tried using the input function

```
func _input(event):
    # Mouse in viewport coordinates.
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        #print("Mouse Motion at: ", event.position)
        look_at(event.position)
    if event is InputEventMouseKey:
        direction = event.position
        print("Mouse Click/Unclick at: ", get_global_mouse_position())
        var shoot = bullet.instance()
        get_parent().add_child(shoot)
        shoot.global_position = global_position
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.08), "timeout")
```

Then I tried using `event.isEcho()` and a state (also used `Input.is_just_pressed()`)

```
enum {
IDLE
SHOOTING
}
```

Here is my current code:
Sprite code (player/gun)

```
extends Sprite

onready var bullet = preload("res://bullet.tscn")
onready var direction = null

var pos = null

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass

func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("click"):
        direction = get_global_mouse_position()
        print("Mouse Click/Unclick at: ", get_global_mouse_position())
        var shoot = bullet.instance()
        get_parent().add_child(shoot)
        shoot.global_position = global_position
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.08), "timeout")

func _input(event):
    # Mouse in viewport coordinates.
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        #print("Mouse Motion at: ", event.position)
        look_at(event.position)
```

Bullet: (not so relevant as my question is why process and input runs twice)

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var direction = Vector2.ZERO
var MAX_SPEED = 20
var ACCELERATION = 5
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO

onready var tween = $Tween

func _ready():
    direction = mouse.direction
    # (81, 23)
    tween.interpolate_property(self, 'position', position, direction, 0.8, Tween.TRANS_LINEAR, Tween.EASE_OUT)
    tween.start()
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.8), "timeout")
    queue_free()
```

I changed the code to:

```
func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("click"):
        set_process(false)
        direction = get_global_mouse_position()
        print("Mouse Click/Unclick at: ", get_global_mouse_position())
        var shoot = bullet.instance()
        get_parent().add_child(shoot)
        shoot.global_position = global_position
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.08), "timeout")
        set_process(true)
```

Still doesn't work.

The _input is run exactly at the same time so that's probably why.

Log:

```
Mouse Click/Unclick at: (453, 177)
Mouse Click/Unclick at: (453, 177)
```

Result:
One bullet comes from (0, 0) going to some random place (I think), and another goes to the right position.

[image]

Sprite 2 is the gun.
sprite is the player character.

[image]

After one click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About your first attempt**

Your first attempt is making little sense to me. What is `InputEventMouseKey`? I know `InputEventMouseButton`.

Anyway, I don't think `event.isEcho()` works for mouse. As echo is - at least historically - a keyboard thing.

And don't use `Input.is_just_pressed()` in `_input`. I have a detailed explanation of that [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69982843/402022).

---

**About your second attempt**

In your second attempt you do this:

```
func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("click"):
```

And this should work. The code you put inside the `if` statement should only run once per `"click"`. Meaning that the game has to get a release and a new press for the code inside the `if` statement to run again.

*The code inside the `if` statement should not be running twice, unless there were two `"click"`. If it is running more times than you expect, I would suspect your - I'm guessing - mouse is faulty.*

---

**What does `yield` do?**

Why are you using `yield` on a timer at the end?

```
yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.08), "timeout")
```

This is what the line of code actually does:

1. Create an `SceneTreeTimer` that will emit a `"timeout"` signal after `0.08` seconds.
2. Schedule the continuation of the method (from that point of the code onwards) to execute after it gets the `"timeout"` signal from the `SceneTreeTimer`.
3. Return. *It returns a `GDScriptFunctionState`.*

To reiterate, `yield` takes an object (in the above example `get_tree().create_timer(0.08)`) and the name of a signal (in the above example `"timeout"`). And it will schedule the execution to continue after that object emits that signal. In other words `yield` awaits the signal form the object (and I say *await* and not *wait* to emphasize that `yield` is not blocking). *I hope this gives you an appreciation for what `yield` does.*

So, when the `SceneTreeTimer` emits the `"timeout"` signal, the execution of the method will resume from that point in the code. *And since that point in the code is at the end of the method, it accomplishes nothing.*

---

Look at this:

```
tween.interpolate_property(self, 'position', position, direction, 0.8, Tween.TRANS_LINEAR, Tween.EASE_OUT)
tween.start()
yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.8), "timeout")
```

Are you trying to await until the tween completed? Write what you mean:

```
tween.interpolate_property(self, 'position', position, direction, 0.8, Tween.TRANS_LINEAR, Tween.EASE_OUT)
tween.start()
yield(tween, "tween_completed")
```

---

And just in case, I'll also say that `yield` is not preventing further calls to `_process` to run. *Just like using `return` does not prevent further calls to the same method to run, and I remind you that `yield` actually returns.* Thus, other calls to `_process` can still happen, and you should be getting one per graphics frame, unless we do something about that.

---

**Disabling `_process`**

If your goal is to stop getting calls to `_process`, then we can do something about that. In particular we can disable `_process`. To do that, you can call `set_process(false)`. And remember you need to call `set_process(true)` to enable it again.

Can we do that with the timer? Sure. It would be something like this:

```
set_process(false)
yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.08), "timeout")
set_process(true)
```

So, `set_process(false)` will disable calls to `_process`, until the call  `set_process(true)`. And the call `set_process(true)` will only happen after the timer completed. *I hope that makes sense.*

Comment: Look in my question ( I added )

Comment: @youlikecodingstackoverflow You changed from `is_action_just_pressed` to `is_action_pressed`. The execution will enter `if Input.is_action_pressed("click"):` every frame that `"click"` is pressed (so if you keep it pressed, it should keep entering). Use `is_action_just_pressed` instead. And having both `_process` and `_input` should not be a problem. Now that you mention the bullet direction: Notice `interpolate_property` takes initial and final values. How are you telling the bullet the destination? Idk what `mouse.direction` is.

Comment: So I changed the bullet code to use ```get_global_mouse_position``` but somehow 1 bullet goes to the right mouse position, but not go from the player to the position and 1 bullet goes from the player but moves along with it (meaning its attached or something) and it doesn't go to the right position

Comment: @youlikecodingstackoverflow You are adding them to the parent `get_parent().add_child(shoot)`, are you moving the parent? Anyway, since you are using global position, then use `global_position` instead of `position` to move the bullet. Another thing you can try is calling `set_as_toplevel(true)` on the bullet so it is always in global space.

Comment: So I am moving the parent. How can I get the node above the parent? I tried get_parent.get_parent, get_root node. Another thing, when I try to get_parent() (which is the moving kinematic body) it gives me null position even though in remote that's where the position is

Comment: @youlikecodingstackoverflow `get_parent().get_parent()` is the parent of the parent. `get_tree().root` is the root of the scene tree. `owner` is the root of the scene file, `get_tree().current_scene` is the root of the current scene (as long as you haven't messed with it). Addendum: I'm not sure what you mean by null position. However, the parent of a node can be null, which is the case if it is the root of the scene tree (or it can happen if the node is not attached to the scene tree).

Comment: I did ```get_parent()``` and it gave me two outputs despite being run once (in ready function), KinematicBody2D and Viewport. I just need to get the position of the KinematicBody2D

Comment: @youlikecodingstackoverflow sounds like you instanced two `KinematicBody2D`, did you? How does your scene tree looks like in execution? If the player character is instanced twice, then it is not that player character is shooting twice, but that each one is shooting.

Comment: put img in question

Comment: I see. Do both sprites have the same script? Or just the gun? If they both have it, they are both shooting. And yes, `get_parent()` should be the `KinematicBody2D` for both. It is usually the `KinematicBody2D` what moves (and it would have the script that takes cares of motion). I still don't know about the null position. Here is an idea: have them include `name` when they `print` (they should say either "Sprite" OR "Sprite2").

Comment: ```root player``` (player is kinematic body I changed it)

Comment: I fixed the problem where it was not going the right directions/starting points, now the only problem is that it's at (0, 0), I need a way to get the KinematicBody2D without getting the viewpoint instead

Comment: @youlikecodingstackoverflow I would make a scene where the `KinematicBody2D` is the root, then the `KinematicBody2D` is the `owner` of the nodes added in that scene. Other ways to go about it include exporting a `NodePath` variable you can configure from the inspector panel, or go about it using `get_parent()`, `find_parent` or `find_node` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone viewing this question, my solution was:

Making the bullet get the mouse position

Making a singleton and making bullet get the pos variable in the player singleton, I updated pos in _process().

Using `Input.is_action_just_released()` instead of the event check because the event is run if the mouse button is clicked AND released (which caused the Input to be ran twice)